# Advanced GWT Components theme CSS not being loaded

Tags: java, css, gwt

I'm trying to use the AdvancedTabPanel of the [Advanced GWT Components](http://advancedgwt.freeforums.org/) library. I've put the JAR file under `war/WEB-INF/lib` and added to my classpath in Eclipse, and added to my HTML file:

```
<link id="advancedTheme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./advanced/themes/default/theme.css"/>
```

Although it finds the Java classes and loads the okay, it doesn't find the CSS. How do I point it to the CSS properly? I can see that the file exists under the JAR, as `org/gwt/advanced/public/advanced/themes/default/theme.css`...

**Edit**: I've also added the `<inherits name="org.gwt.advanced.Grid"/>` tag in my .gwt.xml as indicated in their [Quick Start](http://advanced-gwt.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had initially thought the resources for a module would be dumped into the root of the web server based on the Eclipse plugin's demo project placing some css/html files there - but they're actually located under a path named after the module. Once I changed it to reference `<projectname>/advanced/themes/default/theme.css` (or to reference it with a stylesheet tag in the .gwt.xml file) it worked.